# SQL Query simplification, really slow query 1-2 mins

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

How do I even get start on trying to simplify this mess? It takes such a long time like 1-2 minutes query. I even made a graph structure to see it better (see below). I would really appreciate all the help. I think the nested unions or the "where (0=1)" are making it really slow, but this query currently holds all the data we need.

[image: The structure]

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT LB_ID, 
  LB_KLASGROEP_FK, 
  PL_ID, 
  BO_ID, 
  BO_TYPE, 
  BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK, 
  BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK, 
  BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK, 
  BB_TYPE_FKP, 
  BB_FLAGS, 
  BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  BB_CATEGORIE_FK, 
  VB_TYPE_FKP, 
  VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  BW_ID, 
  BW_TYPE, 
  BW_NUMERIEK, 
  BW_COMMENTAAR, 
  BW_AFWEZIG, 
  BW_LIJSTELEMENT_FK, 
  QLE_CODE, 
  EV_TYPE, 
  EV_DAGELIJKSWERK_FK, 
  EV_EXAMEN_FK, 
  EV_PERIODEEVALUATIE_FK, 
  EV_JAAREVALUATIE_FK, 
  IV_ID, 
  VB_QUOTATIELIJST_FK 
FROM 
  PUNTENBLAD 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      PL_ID AS PLLB_PUNTENBLAD_FK, 
      LB_ID AS PLLB_LOOPBAAN_FK 
    FROM 
      PUNTENBLAD 
      LEFT JOIN LESGROEPDETAILS ON (PL_LESGROEP_FK = LSD_LESGROEP_FK) 
      LEFT JOIN KLAS ON (
        (PL_KLAS_FK = KL_ID) 
        OR (
          (LSD_TYPEGROEPDEEL = 0) 
          AND (LSD_GROEPDEEL_FK = KL_ID)
        )
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN KLASGROEP ON (
        (PL_KLASGROEP_FK = KG_ID) 
        OR (KL_ID = KG_KLAS_FK) 
        OR (
          (LSD_TYPEGROEPDEEL = 1) 
          AND (LSD_GROEPDEEL_FK = KG_ID)
        )
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN LOOPBAANLESEENHEID ON (
        (
          PL_LESEENHEID_FK = LH_LESEENHEID_FK
        ) 
        OR (
          (LSD_TYPEGROEPDEEL = 2) 
          AND (
            LSD_GROEPDEEL_FK = LH_LESEENHEID_FK
          )
        )
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN LOOPBAAN ON (
        (KG_ID = LB_KLASGROEP_FK) 
        OR (LH_LOOPBAAN_FK = LB_ID)
      )
  ) AS PUNTENBLADLOOPBAAN ON (PL_ID = PLLB_PUNTENBLAD_FK) 
  INNER JOIN LOOPBAAN ON (PLLB_LOOPBAAN_FK = LB_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN KLASGROEP ON (LB_KLASGROEP_FK = KG_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN KLAS ON (KG_KLAS_FK = KL_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN INUIT ON (LB_INUIT_FK = IU_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN LEERLING ON (IU_LEERLING_FK = LL_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      BM_PUNTENBLAD_FK AS BO_PUNTENBLAD_FK, 
      BO_ID, 
      BO_TYPE, 
      BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK, 
      BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK, 
      BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK, 
      EV_ID, 
      BM_CODE, 
      BM_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      BM_DATUM, 
      BM_NOEMER, 
      BM_GEWICHT, 
      BM_GEWENST, 
      BM_TYPE, 
      BM_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      BM_PUBLICATIEDATUM, 
      BM_CATEGORIE_FK, 
      BM_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
      NULL AS VB_CODE, 
      NULL AS VB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      NULL AS VB_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
      NULL AS VB_TYPE_FKP, 
      NULL AS VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      NULL AS BB_CODE, 
      NULL AS BB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      NULL AS BB_TYPE_FKP, 
      NULL AS BB_FLAGS, 
      NULL AS BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      NULL AS BB_CATEGORIE_FK, 
      NULL AS BB_NEEDSRECALCULATION 
    FROM 
      BEOORDELINGMOMENT 
      LEFT JOIN BEOORDELING ON (BM_ID = BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK) 
      LEFT JOIN EVALUATIEVERWIJZING ON (
        BM_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK = EV_ID
      ) 
    WHERE 
      (0 = 1) 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      VB_PUNTENBLAD_FK AS BO_PUNTENBLAD_FK, 
      BO_ID, 
      BO_TYPE, 
      BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK, 
      BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK, 
      BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK, 
      EV_ID, 
      NULL AS BM_CODE, 
      NULL AS BM_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      NULL AS BM_DATUM, 
      NULL AS BM_NOEMER, 
      NULL AS BM_GEWICHT, 
      NULL AS BM_GEWENST, 
      NULL AS BM_TYPE, 
      NULL AS BM_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      NULL AS BM_PUBLICATIEDATUM, 
      NULL AS BM_CATEGORIE_FK, 
      NULL AS BM_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
      VB_CODE, 
      VB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      VB_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
      VB_TYPE_FKP, 
      VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      NULL AS BB_CODE, 
      NULL AS BB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      NULL AS BB_TYPE_FKP, 
      NULL AS BB_FLAGS, 
      NULL AS BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      NULL AS BB_CATEGORIE_FK, 
      NULL AS BB_NEEDSRECALCULATION 
    FROM 
      VAKBEOORDELING 
      LEFT JOIN BEOORDELING ON (VB_ID = BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK) 
      LEFT JOIN EVALUATIEVERWIJZING ON (
        VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK = EV_ID
      ) 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      BB_PUNTENBLAD_FK AS BO_PUNTENBLAD_FK, 
      BO_ID, 
      BO_TYPE, 
      BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK, 
      BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK, 
      BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK, 
      EV_ID, 
      NULL AS BM_CODE, 
      NULL AS BM_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      NULL AS BM_DATUM, 
      NULL AS BM_NOEMER, 
      NULL AS BM_GEWICHT, 
      NULL AS BM_GEWENST, 
      NULL AS BM_TYPE, 
      NULL AS BM_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      NULL AS BM_PUBLICATIEDATUM, 
      NULL AS BM_CATEGORIE_FK, 
      NULL AS BM_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
      NULL AS VB_CODE, 
      NULL AS VB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      NULL AS VB_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
      NULL AS VB_TYPE_FKP, 
      NULL AS VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      BB_CODE, 
      BB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
      BB_TYPE_FKP, 
      BB_FLAGS, 
      BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
      BB_CATEGORIE_FK, 
      BB_NEEDSRECALCULATION 
    FROM 
      BEOORDELINGBEREKENING 
      LEFT JOIN BEOORDELING ON (
        BB_ID = BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN EVALUATIEVERWIJZING ON (
        BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK = EV_ID
      )
  ) AS BEOORDELINGEN ON (PL_ID = BO_PUNTENBLAD_FK) 
  LEFT JOIN BEOORDELINGWAARDE ON (
    (LB_ID = BW_LOOPBAAN_FK) 
    AND (
      BEOORDELINGEN.BO_ID = BW_BEOORDELING_FK
    )
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN PUNTENBLADCATEGORIE ON (
    (BM_CATEGORIE_FK = PLC_ID) 
    OR (BB_CATEGORIE_FK = PLC_ID)
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      PLC_ID AS PLCEV_CATEGORIE_FK, 
      EV_TYPE AS PLCEV_TYPE 
    FROM 
      PUNTENBLADCATEGORIE 
      LEFT JOIN PUNTENBLADEVALUATIEWEGING ON (PLC_EVALUATIEWEGING_FK = PLW_ID) 
      LEFT JOIN EVALUATIEVERWIJZING ON (
        PLW_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK = EV_ID
      )
  ) AS CATEGORIEEVALUATIE ON (PLC_ID = PLCEV_CATEGORIE_FK) 
  LEFT JOIN QUOTATIELIJST ON (
    (VB_QUOTATIELIJST_FK = QL_ID) 
    OR (BM_QUOTATIELIJST_FK = QL_ID)
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN QUOTATIELIJSTELEMENT ON (BW_LIJSTELEMENT_FK = QLE_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN EVALUATIEVERWIJZING ON (
    BEOORDELINGEN.EV_ID = EVALUATIEVERWIJZING.EV_ID
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN INGVAK ON (PL_INGVAK_FK = IV_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN DAGELIJKSWERK ON (EV_DAGELIJKSWERK_FK = DR_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN EXAMEN ON (EV_EXAMEN_FK = EX_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN PERIODEEVALUATIE ON (
    (EV_PERIODEEVALUATIE_FK = PEV_ID) 
    OR (DR_PERIODEEVALUATIE_FK = PEV_ID) 
    OR (EX_PERIODEEVALUATIE_FK = PEV_ID)
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN JAAREVALUATIE ON (EV_JAAREVALUATIE_FK = JE_ID) 
WHERE 
  (
    BEOORDELINGEN.EV_ID IN (
      112, 101, 114, 100, 111, 138, 139, 136, 
      141, 135, 137, 127, 128, 125, 130, 131, 
      124, 126, 104, 106, 96, 107, 108, 95, 
      99
    )
  ) 
  AND (
    PL_ID IN (
      781, 815, 722, 728, 806, 705, 741, 808, 
      731, 753, 841, 821, 845, 777, 813, 816, 
      723, 858, 771, 805, 837, 807, 730, 755, 
      840, 822, 846, 778, 820, 817, 724, 859, 
      727, 793, 742, 734, 732, 754, 842, 823, 
      848, 779, 814, 818, 739, 747, 773, 792, 
      745, 735, 733, 756, 844, 824, 847, 811, 
      812, 819, 738, 860, 713, 764, 744, 736, 
      718, 863, 843, 825, 850, 810, 791, 785, 
      740, 748, 772, 765, 838, 749, 719, 861, 
      706, 826, 851, 721, 790, 786, 737, 803, 
      726, 766, 839, 795, 770, 862, 707, 827, 
      849, 801, 782, 787, 833, 855, 762, 715, 
      758, 794, 767, 864, 708, 831, 852, 802
    )
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  PL_ID
```

Comment: You need to give sample data. At a first glance, the first inner select with left joins seem to be totally useless (but you didn't alias the fields, it is unclear what they are).

Comment: You can remove the query that contains `WHERE (0 = 1)` entirely. For this to be answerable, we'd need the DDL of the tables and their indices. I note that you're using an awful lot of left joins some of which are later implicitly converted to inner joins. However, personally, I think the amount of tables is far too much for a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Most columns seem to be implicitly aliased as their names start with an abbreviation of the containing table

Comment: JOINs with OR tend to kill performance, a double join for each condition, or a union usually performs a lot better

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, it feels like hunting that way :) It wouldn't change the fact that the first inner select is useless - I stopped checking the rest there.

Comment: BTW your diagram doesn't match the query.

Comment: you right i will isolate where the porblem is..i think the middel section with the UNIONS OF THE three tables (BEOORDELINGBEREKENING, VAKBEOORDELING,   BEOORDELINGMOMENT) is the more time consuming section " SELECT 
      BM_PUNTENBLAD_FK AS BO_PUNTENBLAD_FK, 
      BO_ID, 
      BO_TYPE, 
      BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK, ........" Is there a better way to rewrite those unions based on the picture of the strucutre i attached? thx guys